# How do I animate an item from a list of items iterated by *ngFor when a user selects it?

Tags: angular

The following code applies animation to all the items when any of them is clicked. I want to apply animation just to the item that the user clicks on. How do I achieve this?

```
@Component({
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of items">
                <div class="item"
                  style="height: 200; width: 400; padding: 20px;"
                  (click)="viewItem(item)"
                  [@zoomItem]="zoomItem">
                       {{ item.name }}
                </div>
             </div>`,
  animations: [
    trigger('zoomItem', [
      state('no', style({transform: 'scale(1)'}),
      state('yes', style({transform: 'scale(1.5)'}),
      transition('no <=> yes', animate('400ms'))
    ])
  ]

})

export class ItemClass {
  zoomItem = 'no';

  viewItem(item) {
    this.zoomItem = 'yes';
    // 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor those `div`s with class `item` into their own components and apply the animation there and make the `ItemClass` the parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item',
  template: `
                <div class="item"
                  style="height: 200; width: 400; padding: 20px;"
                  (click)="viewItem()"
                  [@zoomItem]="zoomItem">
                       {{ item.name }}
                </div>
             `,
  animations: [
    trigger('zoomItem', [
      state('no', style({transform: 'scale(1)'}),
      state('yes', style({transform: 'scale(1.5)'}),
      transition('no <=> yes', animate('400ms'))
    ])
  ]

})

export class Item {
  zoomItem = 'no';
  @Input() item: any;

  viewItem() {
    this.zoomItem = 'yes';
  }
}
```

The `ItemClass` parent component

```
@Component({
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of items">
                <item [item]='item'></item>
             </div>`
})
export class ItemClass {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Dummy. Sorry for taking so long to check the answer :)